# How to do nginx failover on root folder?

Tags: nginx, root, nfs, failover

My nginx processes requests from **/www** which is mounted via NFS.

I also have **/www2** which is also NFS but mounted from another (backup) server. It has the same files as **/www**.

How can I make nginx automatically failover the root directory from **/www** to **/www2** if **/www** is broken?

I tried setting "root /" and then "try_files /www/ethaniel$uri /www2/ethaniel$uri", but that didn't work.

Here is my config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name .ethaniel.com;
    root /www/ethaniel;

    location / {
        index  index.php;
        autoindex off;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(php)$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf.include;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible via nginx config, but you can always script it.

```
#!/bin/sh

#check nfs mount status
df -P -T /storage-pool/nfs-1 | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $2}' | grep nfs | wc -l > /root/status/nfs-1
df -P -T /storage-pool/nfs-2 | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $2}' | grep nfs | wc -l > /root/status/nfs-2

#give time to fetch nfs content
sleep 5

CHECK_FILE_1=`cat /root/status/nfs-1`
CHECK_FILE_2=`cat /root/status/nfs-2`

CHECK_NGINX_1=`grep 'nfs-1' /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf | wc -l`
CHECK_NGINX_2=`grep 'nfs-2' /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf | wc -l`

if [ $CHECK_FILE_1 -ne 1 ] && [ $CHECK_NGINX_1 -eq 1 ] && [ $CHECK_FILE_2 -eq 1 ]
    then
    sed -i 's/nfs-1/nfs-2/g' /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf
        nginx -t && echo 'move to nfs-2'
        nginx -s reload

elif [ $CHECK_FILE_2 -ne 1 ] && [ $CHECK_NGINX_2 -eq 1 ] && [ $CHECK_FILE_1 -eq 1 ]
    then
    sed -i 's/nfs-2/nfs-1/g' /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf
        nginx -t && echo 'move to nfs-1'
        nginx -s reload

elif [ $CHECK_FILE_1 -ne 1 ] && [ $CHECK_FILE_2 -ne 1 ]
        then
        echo 'All nfs-server down'

else
    echo 'OK'

fi
```

Make sure you change the paths to match your environment.